# Get list of pointer/size from Python object satisfying the buffer protocol in C

Tags: python, c, buffer

The buffer protocol (https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) in Python allows representing memory that is potentially non-contiguous. With multiple dimensions, different shapes, sizes and strides, and suboffsets, it can be difficult to unfold exactly where the data actually is in memory.

Before I implement one, I was wondering if there is already somewhere (maybe in the Python C API?), a way to get a list of `(void*, size_t)` pairs in C from a `Py_buffer`, representing all its contiguous portions of memory?

Comment: I don't think your description is quite right.  As I understand it, a buffer such as you're talking about always wraps a single, contiguous block of memory, but the *elements* of the buffer might not be contiguous with each other within the block.  In any case, I'm pretty sure there is not a function in the Python C API to return a list of the contiguous sections that contain elements.

Comment: I think you're right for the most part, unless the suboffsets are used, in which case the pointer needs to be interpreted as an array of pointers, which can point anywhere in memory. That said, even without suboffsets, strides tell you what to skip from contiguous memory, leading to a list of segments.